# After homing all is fine, when printing the Z-axis stops advancing

Tags: z-axis

My Prusa i3 has developed an issue.

It homes fine and has no issues. But, when I press the print button it gives a sneeze (quick screeching noise from the Z-axis stepper motor) and start to print. The only issue then is that there is no lifting on the layers when it prints! When I kill the print, it stops, lifts and goes to the home position as if nothing is wrong.

Video link: [Prusa I3 Z-axis issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syQpJACP7mA)

Does anyone know of a remedy for this issue?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! So the Z-axis does actually work (as you say it lifts after after killing the print)? But it just doesn't work whilst printing? Would it be accurate to say that the Z-axis doesn't work, whilst the X and Y axes are actuating? Or, when you kill the print, are all three axes working fine simultaneously then? I only ask, as I wonder if it some strange issue to do with lack of current - although this is an unlikely stab in the dark, on my part...

Comment: HI, yes, the x and y works fine, the z is just not lifting the 0.28mm  for the layers. this mostly results in a very flat model and blocked nozzle. I'll post a video shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome, I got it fixed!

I've restored to default the Firmware EEPROM Settings in the driver program and it's all fine now. I have no idea how that got changed as I would never go mess around there.

I CAN PRINT AGAIN!!

The program I'm using is Repetier. It has a Firmware configuration setting under the printer settings. The values in there was a bit odd so I took a chance and pressed the Reset to Factory Settings and it worked. There is no version number attached to the setting

Comment: That's great that you found a solution! :-) Still, it is *rather strange* as to what caused it. If you ever do find out, please update your answer. Don't forget to accept your answer in 48 hours time, using the green tick, in order to remove your question from the unanswered list. As we are a beta site, we need to keep the unanswered question queue short, in order to graduate to a full site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: will keep you posted if it happens again.